# SlideDown Effect on div with text

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

## [*jsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/9SsUN/)

I am trying to `slideDown` a `<span>` which is inside a `div` element

```
<div id='delete'>
    <form id='fform'> 
        <span class='front15'>Enter your name </span>

        <input type='text' id='tf' placeholder='name' />
        <input type='submit' id='get_button' value='Get' text='Get'>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Js:**

```
 $('body').on('submit', '#fform', function () {
     $('#delete').html("<span class='front'>Processing...</span>").slideDown('slow');
     // ajax call
     return false;
 });
```

The new span doesn't seem to `slideDown`, it just show's up straight with no effect

What's the problem ?

**Edit:**
  As the Title of the question says : **'..with text'**  none of the answers address to that point. Can you please make the text to slide with div(something like what we see in vertical marquee)

This is what i wanted: thanks to  [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo)

## [*Fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/n6F4D/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the element as hidden, then slide it down :

```
$('body').on('submit','#fform',function(){ 
     var div = $('<div />', {'class': 'front', 
                                text  :'Processing...', 
                                style :'display:none;'
                              }
                );
     $('#delete').html( div );
     div.slideDown('slow');
     return false;
 });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9SsUN/3/)

And `slideDown()` sometimes has issues with inline elements that are not placed properly, so use a block element.

Comment: @JAVAGeek - slideDown() does'nt do that, is this what you're trying to do -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9SsUN/4/)

Comment: Remember that this sets the top value to a negative number to hide the element above the screen, and as such would be reliant on the parents placement and/or overflow etc.

Comment: That is what's my next question.. see this http://jsfiddle.net/n6F4D/
...how to solve this..

Comment: Then you'll need a wrapper, like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/n6F4D/1/) !

Answer (score 0):

The new div is created in the shown state, so is immediately visible on the page.

If you create it hidden, you can then slide it down:

```
$('#delete').html("<span class='front'>Processing...</span>").hide().slideDown('slow');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ua2GM/

Answer (score 0):

The reason it wasn't sliding down because it was already visible. Try to hide it first then slide down:

```
$('#delete').html("<span class='front'>Processing...</span>").hide().slideDown('slow');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9SsUN/2/

Comment: @JAVAGeek I don't get what you means, can you elaboratore more on it?

Comment: as in your fiddle ... the text remain on it's position..it's just `div` that slide's down.. i want to slide down text with div.. so that text too appears as sliding down..

Answer (score 0):

Just replacing the contents of `#delete` with the element as you're doing shows the element immediately. Also, you may want to access the form later, so it's probably best to just hide it.

Here's a slight restructure that achieves the slideDown you want, and only hides the form so you can show it again later on.

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z2gYZ/